integral of $\int d^4y \frac{1}{|y|^4|x-y|^4}$
How can I compute the following integral:
$$
\int{\rm d}^{4}y\,\frac{1}{\left\vert y\right\vert^{4}\,\left\vert\,{x - y}\,\right\vert^4}
$$
I is divergent, but I want to regularize it by a cutoff. First we change to spherical coordinate: ${\rm d}^{4}y =
r^{3}\,{\rm d}r\,{\rm d}\Omega_{3}$, and then regularize the integral by the following:
$$ \int d^4y \longrightarrow \int_{S^3}d\Omega_3 \int_0^\Lambda r^3dr $$

What is the region of integration?

From what OP insinuates in the last line the region of integration is $\Lambda\,\mathbb S^3$. Due to this symmetry we'll employ spherical coordinates in $4$D to try to compute the integral:
$$\int_{\mathbb S^3}\int_0^\Lambda \dfrac{1}{y^4(x^2-2\mathbf x\cdot \mathbf y+y^2)^2}\, y^3\mathrm dy\,\mathrm d\Omega_3(\boldsymbol\varphi)\ ,$$
where $y=|\mathbf y|$ and $x=|\mathbf x|$.
Substituting $\mathrm d\Omega_3=\sin^2(\varphi_1)\sin(\varphi_2)\,\mathrm d\varphi_1\,\mathrm d\varphi_2\,\mathrm d\varphi_3$ (with $\varphi_1, \varphi_2\in[0,\pi]$ and $\varphi_3\in[0,2\pi]$) and rearranging a bit we get to
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\,\mathrm d\varphi_3\int_0^\pi\sin(\varphi_2)\,\mathrm d\varphi_2\int_0^\pi\int_0^\Lambda \dfrac{1}{y(x^2-2\mathbf x\cdot \mathbf y+y^2)^2}\sin^2(\varphi_1)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm d\varphi_1$$
The first two integrals are $4\pi$. To compute the other two we'll assume it is rotated such that $\mathbf x$ lies on the "north pole" axis of $\mathbf y$ and therefore $\mathbf{\hat x}\cdot\mathbf{\hat y}=\cos(\varphi_1)$. Hence, the integral reduces to
$$4\pi\int_0^\pi\int_0^\Lambda \dfrac{\sin^2(\varphi_1)\,\mathrm dy\,\mathrm d\varphi_1}{y(x^2-2yx\cos(\varphi_1)+y^2)^2}$$
There are many ways to tackle this integral but the most secure and maybe quickest one is expanding the integrand for $y<x$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\dfrac{1}{y(x^2-2yx\cos(\varphi_1)+y^2)^2}&=\dfrac{1}{yx^4\left[1-2\dfrac{y}{x}\cos(\varphi_1)+\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)^2\right]^2}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{yx^4}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathcal C_n^{(2)}(\cos(\varphi_1))\left(\dfrac{y}{x}\right)^n,
\end{aligned}$$
This means we can now break that double integral into two of them like so:
$$4\pi\sum_{n\geq 0}\dfrac{1}{x^{n+4}}\int_0^\pi \sin^2(\varphi_1)\,\mathcal C_n^{(2)}(\cos(\varphi_1))\,\mathrm d\varphi_1\,\int_0^\Lambda y^{n-1}\,\mathrm dy$$
To compute that, beforehand, we'll avoid the divergence separating the term $n=0$ from the rest:
$$\dfrac{2\pi^2}{x^4}\int_0^\Lambda \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{y} +4\pi\sum_{n\geq 1}\dfrac{\Lambda^n}{n\,x^{n+4}}\int_0^\pi \sin^2(\varphi_1)\,\mathcal C_n^{(2)}(\cos(\varphi_1))\,\mathrm d\varphi_1$$
To compute these Gegenbauer polynomial integrals first we'll substitute $t=\cos(\varphi_1)$ converting them into
$$\int_0^\pi \sin^2(\varphi_1)\,\mathcal C_n^{(2)}(\cos(\varphi_1))\,\mathrm d\varphi_1=\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-t^2}\,\mathcal C_n^{(2)}(t)\,\mathrm dt$$
Now we'll use its Rodrigues' formula obtaining
$$K_{n}^{(2)}\int_{-1}^1 \dfrac{1}{1-t^2}\,\dfrac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dt^n}(1-t^2)^{n+\frac{3}{2}}\,\mathrm dt$$
where
$$K_{n}^{(\alpha)}=\dfrac{(-)^n\Gamma(\alpha+\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(n+2\alpha)}{\Gamma(2\alpha)\Gamma(n+\alpha+\frac{1}{2})}$$
Furthermore,
$$\dfrac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dt^n}(1-t^2)^{n+\frac{3}{2}}=(1-t^2)^{\frac{3}{2}}\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}\dfrac{(-)^k\Gamma^2(n+\frac{5}{2})}{\Gamma(k+\frac{5}{2})\Gamma(n-k+\frac{5}{2})}(1+t)^k(1-t)^{n-k}$$
and so all derivatives cancel at $t=\pm 1\ \forall n$.
Employing IBP repeatedly we arrive at
$$\begin{aligned}
K_{n}^{(2)}\int_{-1}^1 (1-t^2)^{n+\frac{3}{2}}\,\dfrac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dt^n}\dfrac{1}{1-t^2}\,\mathrm dt&=K_{n}^{(2)}\sum_{k=n}^\infty\dfrac{(2k)!}{(2k-n)!}\int_{-1}^1 t^{2k-n}(1-t^2)^{n+\frac{3}{2}}\,\mathrm dt\\
&=K_{n}^{(2)}\sum_{k=n}^\infty\dfrac{(2k)!}{(2k-n)!}\dfrac{(-)^n[(-)^{2k}+(-)^n]\Gamma(n+\frac{5}{2})\Gamma(k-\frac{n-1}{2})}{2\Gamma(k+\frac{n}{2}+3)}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{16}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{(2(k+n))!}{(2k+n)!}\dfrac{[(-)^{2k}+(-)^n]\Gamma(n+4)\Gamma(k+\frac{n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(k+\frac{3(n+2)}{2})}
\end{aligned}$$
Finally the integral results in
$$\boxed{\dfrac{2\pi^2}{x^4}\int_0^\Lambda \dfrac{\mathrm dy}{y} +\dfrac{\pi\sqrt\pi}{4}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{\Lambda^n}{n\,x^{n+4}}\dfrac{(2(k+n))!}{(2k+n)!}\dfrac{[(-)^{2k}+(-)^n]\Gamma(n+4)\Gamma(k+\frac{n+1}{2})}{\Gamma(k+\frac{3(n+2)}{2})}}$$
Another alternative would've been to solve the radial integral for asymptotic values of $y$ ($\Lambda\to\infty$) in which case the integral is maybe easier to compute using the residue theorem or other techniques.
